# Is there a standard way to store test coverage results to compare them in time?

Tags: python, django, coverage.py

I have a Django project in which I can run coverage and create the report

```
coverage run --source='.' manage.py test my_app
```

I would like to compare the results over time after code refactors.  Is there a way to achieve this without creating my own data model?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None that I know of or could find. And I don't even see enough use for detailed metrics over time to warrant a database for them tbh.

You're generally interested in:

1. general percents (total and by modules/packages) -- to get the general idea of test suite's quality

   - these can be easily extracted from general test reports themselves -- especially if they are sent as e-mails or something which would automatically preserve them.
   - dynamics of this over a long time is only of marginal use as the next-order-of-vanishing value to decide what to prioritize next (the absolute percent and the importance of the module itself are the primary factors). Usually just looking at a few reports several days apart is enough to get the picture.
2. uncovered parts of a specific file -- to decide what tests to write/improve next

   - also of little use over time, especially as code is changed and moved around, so line numbers from an old test run no longer make much sense after even a few commits